# Rails ActiveRecord: Automatically Alias/Append Suffix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, attributes

I've got a legacy database with a bunch of idiotically named columns like:

```
some_field_c
some_other_field_c
a_third_field_c
```

I would very much like to make a Rails ActiveRecord sub-class that automatically aliases these attributes to their name minus the underscore and "c".  However, when I tried:

```
attributes.each_key do | key |
  name = key
  alias_attribute key.to_sym, key[0, (key.length -2)].to_sym if key =~ /_c$/
end
```

in my class definition I got an "undefined local variable or method `attributes'" error.  I also tried overwriting these methods:

```
method_missing
respond_to?
```

but I kept getting errors with that route too.

So my question (actually questions) is/are:

1. Is what I'm trying to do even possible?
2. If so, what's the best way to do it (iterative aliasing or overwriting method missing)?
3. If it's not too much trouble, a very brief code sample of how to do #2 would be awesome.

Thanks in advance for any answers this post receives.

Comment: Can you post a full example this should be fairly easy to get working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is probably that `attributes` is an instance method and you're doing this in the context of the class. The class method that's closest to what you want is `column_names`.

Comment: It worked, thank you!  I did have to put the code in to a method that was called by the sub class to make it to work, and it would have been nice if instead there were some way to say "Run this re-aliasing code right after any sub-class attribute creation occurs", but *shrug* oh well.  Thanks again!

Comment: I tried to paste my working code in here, but the comment formatting ruined it :-(  However, it was essentially the same code as in my question, except with "column_names" instead of "attributes", and no "name = key" (that line was garbage), all defined in a method that is called by the sub-class.

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like:

```
methods.each do |method|
  if method.ends_with("_c") then
    self.send(:defind_method,method.slice(0,-2)){self.send(method)}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... I cooked up this little solution that I thought ended up pretty elegantly...

Not sure if this will work, but I aliased method_missing to still allow active_record to do it's thang:

```
module ShittyDatabaseMethods
  alias :old_method_missing :method_missing

  def method_missing(method)
    if methods.include?("#{method}_c")
      send("#{method}_c".to_sym)
    else
      old_method_missing(method)
    end
  end

end

class Test
  attr_accessor :test_c
  include ShittyDatabaseMethods
end
```

You may not get to name your module "ShittyDatabaseMethods", but you get the idea ;) Once you define that module and stuff it into lib, you just need to include this module and off you go :D

Would love to hear if this works out for you :)

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that won't work :-(  If I do something like

my_shitty_object.some_attribute = 5

that becomes a method call to "some_attribute="; if you append "_c" to that you get "some_attribute=_c" as your method name, instead of "some_attribute_c=".